# Xamarin.Forms REST Web service Call - POST & GET

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms But I'm okay with UI modules development But I need to config the Web service in the project. I preferred REST service, How can I manage rest service in Xamarin.Forms. I've existing service details from the native iOS application. Can you please help me to config the POST and GET service call in Xamarin.Forms. If you share the example of each POST and Get, It would be more helpful for me.

Comment: since it's `.NET` this is how you do it: https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/simple-web-request-with-web-response/215 (request `application/json` and then parse it back to object) => done :D

Answer (score 2):

We have a detailed documentation to access the RESTful webservice to help you. You can find the documentation here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/rest/

Comment: I used to do consume REST web services via - iOS, Angular, and JS but in that blog Xamarin I felt bit different and need a simple example. So that I posted here @Prashant

Answer (score 0):

> Add HttpClient Nuget Package
>
> And Json Package
>
> Using below snippet to consume the REST web service.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://Host/Service.svc/");

string jsonData = @"{""Password"" : ""test@123"", ""UserId"" : ""$test@demo"", ""format"" : ""json""}";
var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync("login", content);

var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

if (result != "")
{

var sessionResponseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sessionResponse>(result);

}
```

Comment: Is this an answer, a comment or an update to the question?

Comment: the answer for the mentioned question.